# Accessing static properties from within an interface declaration

Tags: javascript, typescript, types

```
class A {
    public static readonly TYPE = "A";
}

interface forA {
    for: A.TYPE
}
```

As you can see, I'm trying to access `A.TYPE` from `forA`, so that I can do a form of type guarding.

But, I'm getting the error: `TS2702: 'A' only refers to a type, but is being used as a namespace here`.

Is there a work around for this?

Comment: Use `A['TYPE']` (a [lookup type](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#keyof-and-lookup-types)).

Comment: @jcalz `TS2339: Property 'TYPE' does not exist on type 'A'`

Comment: Whoops didn't notice it was `static`.  You want `(typeof A)['TYPE']`

Comment: Do you know why (typeof A).TYPE doesn't work?

Comment: @Tobiq because `.` is not a valid operator for types.

Comment: is something like this possible: `interface for<T> { type: (typeof T)["TYPE"] }`? I get: `TS2693: 'T' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.`

Comment: No, [types and values are not the same](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50396312/2887218).  You could do `interface forType<T extends { TYPE: any }> { type: T['TYPE'] };` and then `type forA = forType<typeof A>`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to “extract” the type of TypeScript interface property?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36311284/is-there-a-way-to-extract-the-type-of-typescript-interface-property/)

Comment: @jcalz with that example, I'd have to repeated used `typeof` which is not really helpful. I want it to be generic with the type, not this so called "value"

Comment: i.e: `interface forType<T WHERE typeof T extends { TYPE: string }> { type: (typeof T)['TYPE'] };`

Comment: `type forClass<T extends A> = forType<typeof T>` doesn't work

Comment: @jcalz https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54976239/generic-type-guarding-with-typescript

Comment: You can't do `typeof T` if `T` is a type.  You can only do `typeof v` where `v` is a value.  The [answer I linked earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50376977/generic-type-to-get-enum-keys-as-union-string-in-typescript/50396312#50396312) is an explanation of this.  Not sure how else to say this, sorry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The type you're looking for is `(typeof A)['TYPE']` or `typeof (A.TYPE)`.

For the `(typeof A)['TYPE']` notation:

- Static properties are properties of the class constructor, so you need to use `typeof A` instead of `A`.  (The constructor is a *value* named `A`, which is not the same as the type `A`, [despite the same name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50376977/generic-type-to-get-enum-keys-as-union-string-in-typescript/50396312#50396312).  So `typeof A` gives you the type of the constructor)
- And you need bracket notation to [look up](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#keyof-and-lookup-types) a property at the key `"TYPE"`.  For whatever reason, TypeScript doesn't have `.` as a type operator (maybe it would conflict with some namespace notation?).  So it is `(typeof A)['TYPE']` and not `(typeof A).TYPE`.

For the `typeof (A.TYPE)` notation:

- As mentioned above, there is a value named `A` which is the constructor for `A` class instances.  That value has a property named `TYPE`.  So there is a value named `A.TYPE`.  The type of this value can be queried as `typeof (A.TYPE)`.  This is probably the easiest notation for what you're trying to do.

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!