# Generic type guarding with typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

```
abstract class A {

}

class B extends A {
    public static readonly TYPE = "A";
}

interface forValue<T extends { TYPE: string }> {
    type: T["TYPE"]
}
```

The above works perfectly fine, now I want to be able to use this without having to do: `forValue<typeof (T extends A)>` for every subclass of A, T.

So I want something like this:

```
type forClass<T extends A> = forValue<typeof T>;
```

But I get the error `TS2693: 'T' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.`. I don't think typescript is picking up the `typeof` before T. If I replaced T with B, i.e:

```
type forClass<T extends A> = forValue<typeof B>;
```

It works fine.

Is this a bug?

Comment: @jcalz Can I just ask. Is it possible.

Comment: You can't use `typeof` on a generic type parameter. `typeof` needs a value to work on, `T` is just a type. You will need to use `forValue<typeof B>`.