# Typescript : how to do cast to an interface property?

Tags: typescript

How to cast geometryType as I get this error :

> IShape is a Type not a Namespace

for

```
  interface IShape {
    readonly geometryType: "RECTANGLE" | "SQUARE"
  }


  let geometryType = "SQUARE" as IShape.geometryType
  const geometry: IShape = {
    geometryType: geometryType
  }
```

Comment: TS doesn't have *casting* since it doesn't really change anything about your data. Instead it has *type assertion* which is you overriding the compiler to provide a specific type for something. The type system doesn't exist at runtime, however, so this is only a compile time action.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to "extract" the type of TypeScript interface property?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36311284/is-there-a-way-to-extract-the-type-of-typescript-interface-property)

Comment: @FabianLauer thanks I got a right answer below will read your link seems also interesting have to experiment :)

Comment: @VLAZ yes you're right it's not exactly casting but I see it everywhere so I do the same :)

Comment: The difference to casting is quite big. [Here is an example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAaghgGwJYBMDKALOkoF4oBEaAigKoCCASgKIFQA+hNAwgCrkByA4gDK0DcAKEEIIwKAGcskAFyxEqTNmj4CzAJKVmfOnAnzk6aRCGCkAMygAKKcry5VJCjQIBKKAG9BUH1ADGAPYAdhIBogB0CAEA5lYESMAA5PpwkgCOAK5wAE4QBAA0ksauQgC+UBAIEtAW1rY4Dqos7Nw67l6+-sGhEVGx8UkpULl+wHBB0aJuZRVV0B2+9SZQAPQrwBjQoDhBAQDuUEj6BEEQAG4Q2XQARhB+cBnVUHB+gdkoSBNQwAFQrGhQEABDJFYEIFBBRLiaJiKCbXLeXyBEJhCCRGJxPbQLAXZ5QMDZALXUQAW2mglKQA). If it was proper casting, you'd get an exception at runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `as const` to assure typescript that value will not change and it can infer type.

```js
  interface IShape {
    readonly geometryType: "RECTANGLE" | "SQUARE"
  }


  let geometryType = "SQUARE" as const
  const geometry: IShape = {
    geometryType: geometryType
  }
```

You might also want to extract geometry type and use it like here:

```js
type GeometryType = "RECTANGLE" | "SQUARE";

interface IShape {
  readonly geometryType: GeometryType;
}


let geometryType: GeometryType = "SQUARE";

const geometry: IShape = {
    geometryType: geometryType
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `IShape['geometryType']` to get the type for the property `geometryType` from the `IShape` interface.

```
interface IShape {
    readonly geometryType: "RECTANGLE" | "SQUARE"
}


let geometryType = "SQUARE" as IShape['geometryType'];
const geometry: IShape = {
    geometryType: geometryType
}
```