# Get type of an interface's property in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I want to extract a type from my an interface by it's property name to reuse in a Record. I am having difficulties with syntax to retrieve the type by property name. I am trying to make it a bit more future-proof so that whenever id type changes to number for example I don't have to find that one record and change that to number too.

```
interface Account {
  name: string;
  id: string;
  createdOn: number;
}
```

Then in my code I am setting a `useState` type which is a map of `id` (string) from my interface and boolean whether account is currently loading.

```
const [loadingAccounts, setLoadingAccounts] = useState<Record<string, boolean>>({});
```

What do I replace `string` with to get the type of the `id`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to "extract" the type of TypeScript interface property?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36311284/is-there-a-way-to-extract-the-type-of-typescript-interface-property)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can extract a type from interface by using `[]` as follows:

```
interface Account {
  name: string;
  id: string;
  createdOn: number;
}

let testVar: Account['id'];
```

If you will see in this code, type of testVar will be string.

Comment: You may wish to link to the documentation for [indexed access types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html).