# How do I pass Pick as a key inside Record type?

Tags: typescript, react-typescript

Let's say I have an interface

```
  interface Test {
    a: string;
    b: string;
    c: 'x' | 'y' | 'z';
 }
```

How do I construct an object type which requires all the keys of the c union type?

```
Record<Pick<Test, 'c'>, string> // not working
```

Comment: `Record<Test["c"]>`.  `Pick<Test, "c">` will give you `{ c: 'x' | 'y' | 'z' }`. It's like the opposite of `Omit`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to "extract" the type of TypeScript interface property?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36311284/is-there-a-way-to-extract-the-type-of-typescript-interface-property)