# Get the return type from a method parameter

Tags: javascript, typescript

I would like to get the of the return type from a method where I pass the key as a parameter and the return is type from the interface.

I looked at this answer [Is there a way to "extract" the type of TypeScript interface property?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36311284/is-there-a-way-to-extract-the-type-of-typescript-interface-property) and the way the answers seem to show is when you use a string literal. I however don't know what the string will be passed in as. How can get the type without knowing what the parameter will be?

Here is the closes I have gotten based on the above answer, but it still shows an error

> Type 'T' cannot be used to index type 'Partial<GameOptions>'.

```js
interface GameOptions {
  production: boolean;
  background: string;
  stats?: boolean;
  objects?: new() => object
}

export class MyClass {
  // Set through a method in another class constructor
  #options: Partial<GameOptions> = {};

  get<T = keyof GameOptions>(option: T): GameOptions[keyof GameOptions] {
    return this.#options[option];
  }
}
```

```js
this.#production = this.gameConfig.get('production');
```

> Type 'string | boolean | new() => object | undefined' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're pretty close. 2 fixes:

1. Use `T extends` instead of `T =`
2. Index `GameOptions` by `T`

```
export class MyClass {
  get<T extends keyof GameOptions>(option: T): GameOptions[T] {
    return this.#options[option];
  }
}
```

Comment: Nice! I had to do also tell it what to return: `return this.#options[option] as GameOptions[T];`

Comment: You might need to check if `options` is correctly typed, it's not showing any errors for me. https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgOJwLYQPIAczAD2IAzsgN4CwAUMsgEaIDWA5lIQK4gAmAXMiTBRQLANw06guGBIB+fvUKEANhDghxtZIXoArCAhnzkICAHcAFAEpkAXgB82vQbA0AvjRrcDyuFBQIxILa+ESk-OhYeARBmjQQAB64hFBgyAi+JGQAsgCeAMKZZFRaLBBgADwAKsiJkDxkTBC5hDBomDihQfYWhF0g-FVWER3RYSQA2lUAuhQSdMj+YBxQICExpBN9G9OadB7UBzSBpGmQwbYm5sh5hXBZ1gB0ZWAWAORSMm9WokA

Comment: I think its because I am using `Partial` https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgOJwLYQPIAczAD2IAzsgN4CwAUMsgEaIDWA5lIQK4gAmAXMiTBRQLANw06guGBIB+fvUKEANhDghxtZIXoArCAhnzkICAHcAFAEpkAXgB82vQbA0AvjRrcDyuFBQIxILa+ESk-OhYeARBmjQQAB64hFBgyAi+JGQAsgCeAMKZZFRaAMSEoUH8AAp+BHDKADyROJWkjrYUbpp0LBBgjQAqyImQPGRMELmEMGiYrTHtFhWL-INWEfPRYSQA2oMAuhQSdMj+YBxQIMhgABbAJAB05W17K2EHPcge1D80gaQ0pBgp1TGZkHlCnAstZHn0wBYAORSGSIqyiIA

Comment: Ah yeah. You need to use return type `GameOptions[T] | undefined`.