# How do I define in a argument of a function when I have a nested interface and I want to get only the object?

Tags: typescript, types, properties

I have a function that uses only `pointData` object.

```js
interface AllTheDatas{
 id: string
 pointData: {
  square: string
  triangle: string
 }
}
```

I'd like to use only the pointData object, but I don't know how to type it in a function argument:

```js
// do something
buildPointData(AllTheDatas.pointData)
```

```js
function buildPointData(pointData: ?????){
 // do something

 return `${AllTheDatas.square}--${AllTheDatas.triangle}
}
```

I tried to use Partial, Pick<AllTheDatas, 'pointData'> but it doesn't work, returning an error expecting the 2 keys and values inside of pointData object.

I know that I can do something like {x: string, y: string} but since I have a AllTheDatas interface, can't I just try to reuse it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to "extract" the type of TypeScript interface property?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36311284/is-there-a-way-to-extract-the-type-of-typescript-interface-property)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to just extract the type into a separate interface and give it a proper name:

```
interface PointData {
  square: string;
  triangle: string;
}
interface AllTheDatas {
  id: string;
  pointData: PointData;
}
```

Then you can just use that named type in your function parameter declaration:

```
function buildPointData(pointData: PointData) {
  … // do something
}
```

---

An alternative is to refer to a property of the `AllTheDatas` type via an [indexed access type expression](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html). You can write

```
function buildPointData(pointData: AllTheDatas["pointData"]) {
  … // do something
}
```