# How to get the type of a key of an interface?

Tags: typescript

How can I get the type of `User.name`?

```
interface User {
  id: number;
  name: string;
}
```

I want to be able define my other type like.

```
type UserInstance {
  name: <infer type "string" from User interface>;
  ...
}
```

The purpose is to make it dynamic: If type "string" changes in time, I don't need to go and change it everywhere.

Comment: Are you looking for `User["name"]`? If not, maybe give some more details about what you plan to do with the type. Keep in mind the types will only exist at compile time.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to "extract" the type of TypeScript interface property?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36311284/is-there-a-way-to-extract-the-type-of-typescript-interface-property)

Comment: I want to create some type like
`type UserInstance = { name: <infer the type "string" from the User interface> }`

Comment: Yes it does, thank you! (Sorry for my delayed reaction.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Retrieve the name of the property you want with bracket notation as follows (and already provided in the question comments):

```js
interface User {
  id: number;
  name: string;
}

type UserInstance = {
  name: User["name"]
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Some ways

First : not recomended .
USER.name = (((every thing you want))) and if it throws an error ,it says its type by that error details.

Second : select the word((( USER.na》|《me))) and press f12 to see its Ref or type directly.

This  》|《 is sample of your mouse cursor .I mean select the word ((name)) or ((USER)) where you are using it